# Changing the size of a shape in PowerPoint VBA Macros

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I'm trying to resize a shape (square) using VBA in PowerPoint when clicking on one of the 4 circles in each vertex of a square. But when I resize it to the position of the mouse it only works in the right bottom vertex of the square.

I want it to size up in the upper vertexes and left in the left side vertexes.  Because it only sizes to the lower right. I tried messing with the Top property of the shape and many codes, but non of them worked.

**EDIT:** Can I use the ScaleHeight and ScaleWidth property for that? If yes, then can you help me with that, because that property is confusing, beacause I have to use factor...

Here is the last code I tried:

```
Sub resizeshp_topright3()
Dim llCoord As POINTAPI
GetCursorPos llCoord
Shapes("a").TextFrame.TextRange.Text = Shapes("shp").Height

Shapes("shp").Width = (llCoord.Xcoord / 1.417323) - Val(Replace(Shapes("shp").Left, ",", "."))
Shapes("shp").Top = (llCoord.Ycoord / 1.417323)
Shapes("shp").Height = (llCoord.Ycoord / 1.417323) - Val(Replace(Shapes("shp").Top, ",", "."))
End Sub
```

Comment: Ok, I added the last code I tried.

Comment: What does POINTAPI return?
Shapes().top, .Width, etc returns a value in points.

Comment: I have a code in a Module that will return the cursor position. llCoord.Xcoord returns the X position and llCoord.Ycoord the Y position of the cursor.

Comment: Then you problem is that the x/y coordinates of the cursor are not what shapes().top, width, etc needs to be set to.  You are going to have to translates the coordinates to the values of the shape position/dimensions

Comment: No, that's not the problem (I already solved that with the "/ 1.417323").